# Copy and Paste value when it changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to write a code to :

- copy cell A14 into the first row of column H,
- move down the entire column (most recent data on top),
- and then time stamp in column I when the value changes

But I cannot seem to get it running and working properly.

I am trying to keep real time tracking of these values and create a time series graph.

This needs to execute on its own.

Any thoughts?

```
Private Sub Gain(ByVal target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = True


Do While cell("A14") <> cell("H1")
If cell("H1") <> cell("A14") Then
Range("H1:J1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A14").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("H2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A16").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("I2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("B16").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("J2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Columns("I:I").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: I think you should show us your code. Also, take a look at the WorkSheet_Change event.

Answer (score 0):

This will track any changes and paste the current time in Column I.  It looks like your copying and pasting code should be working; if not, please let us know what (if any) errors or results you are getting.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
rng = Range("A:A")

If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
    'Do nothing
Else:

    If Target.Value <> Now Then

        Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value = Now
        Cells(Target.Row, 9).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    Else
    End If
End If

End Sub
```